# EstimoteProximitySDK crashing my app after upgrading to Xcode 10 GM seed

Tags: ios, xcode, estimote

I have recently installed the GM seed version of Xcode 10, and after doing the necessary swift 4.2 conversions, my project is building correctly but crashes on runtime with the following debugger message

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __T0BOWV
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/05F7236E- B1DB-4811-B9E2- 20BA82908ABD/****/Frameworks/EstimoteProximitySDK.framework/EstimoteProximitySDK
Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/05F7236E-B1DB-4811-B9E2-20BA82908ABD/****/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/05F7236E-B1DB-4811-B9E2-20BA82908ABD/****/Frameworks/EstimoteProximitySDK.framework/EstimoteProximitySDK`
```

Any ideas on what might be the issue and how to fix it? I want to understand why is this happening more than how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like theres an update to the SDK, which is working for me.

Try using the following in your pod file or update from the related branch.

```
pod 'EstimoteProximitySDK', '= 1.1.0-swift4.2'
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the branch you're installing from? Like what's the line you're writing in your podfile?

Comment: pod 'EstimoteProximitySDK', '= 1.1.0-swift4.2'

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools selected at "Xcode 10", then, compile the frameworks again.

It seems like the frameworks compiled by Xcode 9.4 or earlier Xcode version, which is not support in Xcode 10.0.

Comment: I tried this solution, but my command line tools had already Xcode 10.0 selected.